# normal subgroup of a group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose we have a prime number $p$ as well as a positive integer $n$. Consider a group $G$ with $p^n$ elements. I want to prove that $G$ has a normal subgroup with $p^{n-1}$ elements. I found this in the book I am reading. When I think about it, it makes sense, but I was a little iffy on how to prove it.

Comment: Hint: Such a group has a non-trivial center. Take the quotient by the center and apply induction.

Comment: Are you sure that is a duplicate. It looks like they showed it for $p^{n+1}$ on that one

Comment: @user113561 The proof in the other question is more general. It shows that there is a normal subgroup of order $p^k$ for all $0 \le k \le n$, not just $p^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT.** First, use the class formula
$$
|G|=|Z(G)|+\sum_{a \in G,\; a \notin Z(G)} |G:C(a)|
$$
to show that $|Z(G)|>1$ (that is the center is nontrivial), where the $a \in G$ are distinct representatives for the conjugacy classes of $a \in G$.

Finally, use induction on $k$ to show that $G$ has a *normal* subgroup of order $p^k$ for $0 \le k \le n$.